# What should be optimal number of threads in an application?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

My application fires only SELECT queries on Oracle DB. I have multiple schema and I am having one thread to read from each schema. Each thread creates its own connection to connect to DB.

When I ran three tests I observed that the performance is best for 8-10 threads and degrades after that on a single core Machine. Does anyone know if there is any reason for that?

Comment: How many disks do you backend your database schemes?

Comment: just one disk in the back end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general rule or a simple math equation for this. Usually the best is one thread per core, but it depends. The only way to tell is by testing your application. Having 8-10 threads on a single core machine in your case is bad, the threads will spent more time in dealing with each other instead of doing actual work.

Comment: If the threads are io bound it makes  sense  to have several ones here.

Comment: @AlexandreC. couldn't agree more.

Comment: Yes. I write the result of a query to a file. When I use one thread it takes 10 sec. with 2 threads 8 seconds, with 5 threads 4 seconds, with 8 threads 3 sec. and after that it again starts increasing.

Comment: I think it is because a threshold is reached after which context switching loses its advantage.[As Eugene rightly said]  One thread per CPU might not be a useful guideline, because OS does not guarantee that each thread will run on a separate core.